# Parsing XML Nodes result in list all of the same item

Tags: c#, xml, list, xmlnode, ebay-api

I've ran into this issue in previous projects, but have never understood why this happens, and would appreciate any information in that regard, and how to consistently avoid the issue.

I have an inventory report from eBay in XML format.  I am parsing the SKU node into a List to determine what products we have in inventory that are not listed on eBay.

The code snippet below results in a list, all of the same SKU.  I have verified that the XmlNodeList is populated with roughly 8000 unique strings.  I believe the error is related to an under the hood pointer / reference kind of issue.. like I am using temporary memory space to store the XmlNode object and the returnList points to that memory location, rather than doing a memcpy type of operation to transfer the string into the list.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BulkDataExchangeResponses xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <ActiveInventoryReport>
        <SKUDetails>
            <SKU>FAKE0012</SKU>
            <Price currencyID="USD">5.99</Price>
            <Quantity>12</Quantity>
            <ItemID>123456789123</ItemID>
        </SKUDetails>               
    </ActiveInventoryReport>
</BulkDataExchangeResponses>
```

Code Listing:

```
private List<string> getListingsFromXML(string fileName)
    {
        List<string> returnList = new List<string>();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("ebay", "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents");
        doc.Load(fileName);
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("//ebay:ActiveInventoryReport",ns);

        XmlNodeList skus = node.SelectNodes("//ebay:SKUDetails",ns);

        foreach (XmlNode sku in skus)
        {
            XmlNode tempNode = sku.SelectSingleNode("//ebay:SKU",ns);
            if (tempNode != null)
            {
                //tempNode.InnerText is always the first SKU in skus
                //sku iterates through list as expected.
                returnList.Add(tempNode.InnerText.Trim());
            }
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

Comment: I guess you shouldn't use absolute expressions `"//ebay:SKUDetails"` and `"//ebay:SKU"` but relative to the context node `"ebay:SKUDetails"` and `"ebay:SKU"`

Comment: Just saw this answer as I came to the same conclusion.  I haven't used XML namespaces much at all, so didn't realize the // made the reference absolute.  Feel free to post an answer and I will accept!

Comment: If you down vote a question, please leave reasoning.  I believe the question was concise, well formatted and included complete code listing to determine the cause.

Comment: I did a comment only since it was a small issue. Now that you have found the solution you should accept your answer to close the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue.  The // creates absolute pathing in the XML document so it somehow or another retrieves the first node every time.  Removing it fixed the problem.  Corrected code:

```
private List<string> getListingsFromXML(string fileName)
    {
        List<string> returnList = new List<string>();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("ebay", "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents");
        doc.Load(fileName);
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("//ebay:ActiveInventoryReport", ns);

        XmlNodeList skus = node.SelectNodes("//ebay:SKUDetails", ns);

        foreach (XmlNode sku in skus)
        {
            XmlNode tempNode = sku.SelectSingleNode("ebay:SKU", ns);
            if (tempNode != null)
            {
                returnList.Add(tempNode.InnerText.Trim());
            }
        }

        return returnList;
    }
```

I saw the comment from @wero after submitting answer.  Post answer, and I will gladly accept.